# VS 2012 Managed C++ Crash

Tags: visual-studio-2012, managed-c++

After upgrading a managed c++ assembly from VS2010 to VS2012 I'm getting a very strange crash (Debug) that only happens in the 2012 code branch (which is identical).  I have some code that reads from the registry and allocates a BYTE array to store results in.  The registry calls have been commented and are NOT a factor.

```cpp
DWORD nDataSize=20;
BYTE* lpValueData=new BYTE[nDataSize];
delete [] lpValueData;
```

I've isolated the crash (cx0000005) to the delete [] call.  If I comment the function, the code no longer crashes.

Comment: Simply allocating then deleting a block of data should obviously work, so either 1) the implementation is completely broken, or 2) you're doing something in other code that's causing a problem (probably writing outside the memory you've allocated). I vote for #2. As an aside, it's either C++, or C++/CLI or Managed C++, but despite the "C++" in their names, the other two are *not* C++, so tagging as both doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Nothing else accesses that variable, and I immediately delete it and receive the crash.  Commenting those two lines produces code that doesn't crash.

Comment: I'm almost tempted to say "[sscce](http://sscce.org/) or it didn't happen." In reality, you probably have some other code that's writing outside its bounds and messing up the heap, after which this delete  triggers the problem even though it didn't really cause it.

Comment: This is not managed code.  Heap corruption is a universal issue with native code, the code that crashes never has anything to do with the source of the corruption.  There's nothing in your question that helps us help you.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree that heap corruption looks to be the culprit, however, this code has been in production in vs2010 for a couple of years with no crashes in this area.  The ONLY thing that has changed is the compiler.  I'm wondering if there is a different approach within the compiler, or some new compiler switch I should be utilizing.

Comment: Are you using threads? Another thread could manage to corrupt the heap between the allocation and the free.